# How to run multiple composed commands (with multiple arguments) in gnu parallel?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I want to run the following scripts with different input arguments using `GNU Parallel` in parallel:

```
Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 1 #(1) 0.1 and 1 are the input arguments
Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 2 #(2)
Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 5 #(3)
Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 10 #(4)
```

So all I wanna do is run the 'commands' (1),(2),(3),(4) in parallel using GNU parallel.

My best guess was something like

```
parallel Rscript < svmRScript_v2.copy.r ::: 0.1 1 ::: 0.1 2 ::: 0.1 5 ::: 0.1 10
```

I know this is entirely wrong and I'm getting the following error:
`Fatal error: cannot open file ':::': No such file or directory`.

Any suggestion what I need to change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `Rscript` require a file argument? Drop the `<`, since it appears `Rscript` is trying to read `:::` as its argument rather than `svnRScript_v2.copy.r`.

Comment: Yes. Originally, in the command line I'd run it as `Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 1 &` . It's like bash program.sh arg1 arg2 ; arg1 and arg2 are the inputs to the program.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious is:

```
parallel Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r 0.1 ::: 1 2 5 10
```

But I have the feeling you might want `0.1` and `0.2` later:

```
parallel Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r ::: 0.1 0.2 ::: 1 2 5 10
```

If the order of the arguments is wrong:

```
parallel Rscript svmRScript_v2.copy.r {2} {1} ::: 0.1 0.2 ::: 1 2 5 10
```

Did you have a chance to watch [the intro videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1) and [walk through the tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html)?